# How to replace empty Designer.cs text

Tags: c#, replace, visual-studio-2017

Greeting all, this is my first question, I've been trying to search the asked questions about what I want to ask and try some tips from other questions with no luck so far. So I decompiled an old project with dotPeek, because there is no Designer.cs file for the forms I create them manually and I empty the files. Then I want to replace the content of all the Designer.cs files (which is empty, no code at all) with blank form Designer.cs code (I have installed multiline find/replace extension for visual studio, o yeah I use visual studio 2017) but I can not find how to replace empty character from replace. Is there a way or should I do it manually? I really hope there is a way because the file is many (almost 400 files). Or is there any solution to separate the code for the designer to Designer.cs files automatically?
I want to populate all the empty Designer.cs files with this code

```
namespace winapp
{
partial class XtraForm1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "XtraForm1";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share the sample of code which you want to replace with the another sample code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use find/replace to populate empty files?

Comment: Yes I want to use find/replace to populate emtpy files

Comment: As there's nothing in the empty files, by definition there's nothing to find.I don't think find/replace will work for you. Perhaps better to write a small script or program to go through the files and populate them.

Comment: Can you help with the script? I really don't have clue how to do that

Comment: Or is there any application to help with something like that?

Comment: I found the solution a small free application called fnr.exe in http://findandreplace.io/